# Add specific headers for each request in Angular

Tags: angular, http-headers, angular-http-interceptors

If I have an interceptor that adds headers for each request, but in each request I must add additional headers specific to each request, how can I add those headers?

(I omit imports of httpClient and others)

```js
// any.interceptor.service.ts

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
  const authToken = this.auth.getAuthorizationToken();
  const authReq = req.clone({
    headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authToken)
  });
  return next.handle(authReq);
}
```

```js
// my.service.ts

@Injectable({
provideIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  send(data: AnyInterface) {
    // *******************
    // adding HERE additional specific headers
    // *******************
    this.http.post(URL, data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve the issue. [Reading this article](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-httpheaders/#httpheaders-are-immutable) I was able to understand that HttpHeaders are immutable, so the solution to @Emilien would only have to modify the following:

```js
send(data: AnyInterface) {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('YOUR_HEADER_KEY', 'YOUR_HEADER_VALUE');
  this.http.post(URL, data, { headers });
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Then you could try this :

```js
send(data: AnyInterface) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('YOUR_HEADER_KEY', 'YOUR_HEADER_VALUE');
    this.http.post(URL, data, { headers });
  }
```

Comment: is `post(URL,data,{headers:headers})`

Comment: @Eliseo, in typescript (I guess ECMA6+ aswell), if you have an object wich have an attribute wich have as value other object with the same name of the attribute, you can leave just the attribute name. const myObject={...};   antotherObjetc{attr1:1,attr2:'example', myObject: myObject } is the same as antotherObjetc{attr1:1,attr2:'example', myObject }

Comment: Hi @Emilien, I have put your solution in 2 different projects and it doesn't work :(. It is only possible to see the interceptor headers.